# .NET Standard + .NET Framework: could not load file or assembly 'Ninject'

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, .net-standard

## **SITUATION**

I have the following solution structure:

```
 - solution
     - "WPF Client" PROJECT[.NET Framework 4.6.1] 
       (has ref to: "Core Logic" PROJECT, "Service Provider" PROJECT)
    
     - "Core Logic" PROJECT[.NET Framework 4.6.1] 
       (has ref to: "Service Provider" PROJECT)
    
     - "Service Provider" PROJECT[.NET Standard 2.0] 
       (has nuget: "Ninject")
```

and I have following classes

*IoC.cs* in **Service Provider PROJECT**

```
public static class IoC
{
    private static readonly IKernel mKernel;

    static IoC()
    {
        mKernel = new StandardKernel();

        Setup();
    }

    private static void Setup()
    {
        mKernel.Bind<IInput>().To<Input>();
    }

    public static T Get<T>()
    {
        return mKernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

*MyViewModel.cs* in **Core Logic PROJECT**

```
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
    ...
    public void MyViewModelMethod()
    {
        var a = IoC.Get<IInput>(); 
    }
    ...
}
```

*MyView.xaml.cs* in **WPF Client PROJECT**

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        viewModel.MyViewModelMethod();
    }

}
```

## **PROBLEM**

whenever I try to run my project it throws following error:

> could not load file or assembly 'Ninject'

## *Edit*

I think this does NOT have to do anything with ninject... it's rather a .net standard + .net 4.6.1 issue.

the reason I'm thinking this way is: first of I tried other IoC containers and they threw the same error message. BUT it doesn't end there... whenever I install any NuGet package on my **.NET Standard** Project it seems to not be able to load its assemblies into my client project (**.net 4.6.1**)

the question is: is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: Try to remove the assembly in packages folder then in `package.config` as well.

Re-add using nuget

Comment: @Pseudorandom If You mean removing 'Ninject' from `packages.config` and packages folder, then it wasn't there already.

Comment: Is your ninject from NuGet package? or just a referenced DLL?

Comment: @Pseudorandom a Nuget package, however I don't see any 'Ninject' like folders in my packages folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!

You have to migrate Your `packages.config` into Your **.csproj** file.

for more details lookup [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481).